# How to integrate rest Api with Magento

Tags: api, rest, magento, integration

Hello I have Third Party REST API And I want to integrate that REST API with my Magento Project 
so, is that Possible in Magento??
And If Yes then how to integrate it in my Magento Project
Please Help......
Thank in advance

Comment: take a look for ex. at the new PayPal module for Magento - it should have an integration with the PayPal REST API - and just do it similarly at the very end you will probably have sth like: `$response = $client->call(METHOD_NAME, $optionsArray));`

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

Magento has a REST API, more usually with Soap Client.

Some examples: http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html

Try to use last version (V2) of integration and get attention for examples that is for V2 Magento API.

First you need to create user to consume this API:

Magento Admin -> System -> Web Service -> SOAP/XML Users

and create your user for get api integration functionality.

Comment: SOAP API is not equal to REST API.